# About wordpress post types templates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

A have problem with templates of custom post types in wordpress. This is my function.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_door' );

function register_cpt_door() {

$args = array( 
    'hierarchical' => true,

    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,

    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'door'),
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'door', $args );

}
```

I use single-door.php for single page and it works. But I tried to use category-door.php and archive-door.php for category, both of them does not work, and wordpress return index.php.

What template name should I use?

Comment: Code of custom post types was generated here http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `category-door.php` is the template for a category with the slug `door`. `archive-door.php` is the template for the custom post type archive, not a template for posts with the type door that are in a particular category.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Taxonomy terms can belong to multiple post types so there is no way to create a template for taxonomies within the scope of a particular post type.

The solution here is to create a custom taxonomy for doors:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Once you create your custom taxonomy (I'll call it `door-categories`) you can create a template terms in that taxonomy in the `taxonomy-door-categories.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg).

The file `category-door.php` would be for the category with slug *door*.

The file `archive-door.php` is for the main archive of your custom post type, that you have enabled with the option `'has_archive' => true`. It's not for the category index.

For your custom post you used the taxonomy `category` that exists in Wordpress by default, so you can use the template file `category.php`.
Inside the loop you can check the post type and give it a different class/style:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if( 'door' == get_post_type() ): ?>

        <div class="door">
            This is a door
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div class="post">
            This is a post
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Otherwise if you want different categories for you custom post type than you need to [register a new taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Answer (score 0):

```
Custom Post Type in wordpress. Basic four steps 

Step 1 : File Path location : theme/function.php in your theme

  Paste code in function.php (register custom post type )

  <?php

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_func' );
function custom_post_type_func() {
    //posttypename = services
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'services', 'services' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'services' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New services', 'services' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit services', 'services' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New services', 'services' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View services', 'services' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search services', 'services' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No services found', 'services' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No services found in Trash', 'services' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent services:', 'services' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description' => 'Hi, this is my custom post type.',
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post'
);
register_post_type( 'services', $args );
}
?>
```

Step 2: how can show wordpress custom post type in wordpress template page ?

```
  : you can show anywhere in template page like this :



<?php   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="services-items">
            <?php the_title(); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>'; }

?>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Step 3: Create new template for show single post like this

single-{custom post type name}.php
       or
single-services.php

Step 4: Paste code in single-services.php file

```
 <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="main-post-div">
                <div class="single-page-post-heading">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content-here">
                <?php  the_content();  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-section-here"
                <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is  custom post type example with single post page.